# How to pause a void in C++ Arduino Uno

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

My question is very simple but I'm stuck on it for a while now.

I need to make a script that when pushed on a button loop a() is put on pause. And when you press it again it should go from where it ended. But I can't figure out a way to do it.

I hope someone can help me.

This is my code:

```
int Aan = 1;
int Uit = 0;

int analogPin = A3;

int LED1 = 13;
int LED2 = 12;
int LED3 = 11;
int LED4 = 10;

int val;
bool r = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(analogPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED1, Aan);
  digitalWrite(LED2, Aan);
  digitalWrite(LED3, Aan);
  digitalWrite(LED4, Aan);
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(analogPin);
  if (val == LOW)
  {
    if (r == true)
    {
      r = false;
    }
    if (r == false)
    {
      r = true;
    }
  }
  if (r == true)
  {
    a();
  }
}
void a() {
  for (int i = 10; i <= 13; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, Uit);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(i, Aan);
  }
  for (int i = 13; i >= 10; i--)
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, Uit);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(i, Aan);
  }
}
```

Just to explain whats happening.. Void a() makes 4 different leds light up and go out. The pattern thats used is Knight Rider (If you don't know the tv show just google the car of him)

Comment: Instead of thinking about it as 'pausing', I would think of saving the state in the sequence that you left off at. You could init 'i' in your for loop to be whatever you left off at when you stopped last time

Comment: @CameronWhite Can you please also include some code? What may help me with my problem? Instead of only saying something.. I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Please explain what this program is supposed to do? Are the led's supposed to constantly blink and you want that blinking to stop when the button is pushed?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I edited the question.. I'm sorry that it wasn't clear enough for you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you want the "Knight Rider" pattern to constantly run.

I've made a couple of changes. First, I added a function to run the led sequence one way. Second, I added a `while` loop that will always run once, and will continue to run while the button is pushed.

```
bool paused = false;
int buttonState = HIGH;

void loop() {
    a();
}

// This only works if leds ports are consecutive
void runSequence(int ledStart, int ledEnd)
{
    int direction = ledStart < ledEnd ? 1 : -1;
    for (int i = ledStart; i != ledEnd + direction; i += direction) {
        digitalWrite(i, Uit);
        do {
            delay(100);
        } while (LOW == digitalRead(analogPin));  // Check button state
        digitalWrite(i, Aan);
    }
}

void a() {
  runSequence(LED4, LED1);
  runSequence(LED1, LED4);
}
```

**EDIT** Changes based on comment

```
bool paused = false;
int buttonState = HIGH;

int currentLED = LED1;
int currentDirection = -1;

void loop() {
    checkButton();
    if (!paused) {
        // Flash the led
        digitalWrite(currentLED, Uit);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(currentLED, Aan);
        // Change direction?
        if (LED1 == currentLED || LED4 == currentLED) {
            currentDirection *= -1;
        }
        // Setup for next iteration
        currentLED += currentDirection;
    }
}

void checkButton() {
    int state = digitalRead(analogPin);
    // Check if button state has changed
    if (state != buttonState) {
        buttonState = state;
        // Change paused state when button is released
        if (state == HIGH) {
            paused = !paused;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! But is there anyway that if I release the button it will be on pause until I press it again?

Comment: I made a change to do that. It's untested, so there might be bugs. This example is more like your original code.

Comment: This actually doesn't work unfortunatly.. Only if I keep the button pressed until a() is finished it stops..

Comment: That is correct. I've updated to have it check the button in the `for` loop.

Comment: It's almost perfect.. But if it isn't tomuch work.. Can you maybe make it so that it remembers where it left of? So if you press pause when it's on led 2.. It starts at led2 when you continue it. And make it so that (in this case) led 2 is on when on pause? I'm sorry for all the work you may have to do for this..

Comment: Where's the fun in that :). You just need to keep track of 2 variables: last led lit and direction. I'm at work right now. If I get some time I'll try to do it, but in the mean time, you should give it a go.

Comment: Alright! I'm gonna go to sleep first xD Gonna get some rest and start with a fresh mind tomorrow :) If you find a solution please just post it here because that actually helps me the most when I'm learning new programlanguages. Really appreciate the help so far!

Comment: OK. Updated again.

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your a() function put another while loop which becomes false when the button is Up.

Like:

```
while(digitalRead(analogPin) == LOW)
{
}
```

As long as the button is pressed down the loop will continue. When you release the button the program will exit the loop and continue execution of your code.